# How to run pytest tests after docker container starts

Tags: python, node.js, docker, github, pytest

I would like to ask if it's possible to run a set of tests written in python (pytest)
on a running NodeJS application running in Docker?

What I want to achieve:

1.setup github action to run and build the 'test Docker container' on pull_request (done)

2.run pytest as soon as the node container starts **(pending)**

3.run another github workflow based on the test results of pytest (there is also a question how to achieve it,I saw somewhere that maybe cypress can help)

Please let me know if I should provide Dockerfile if it's necessary
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile, where I put my bash script which run npm start & pytest -c xxx